# cast Worksheetclass to _worksheet C#

Tags: c#, excel

just trying to build an excel file and am turning a lot of text files into individual worksheets. I made what I thought was a pretty simple method, but it claims I'm trying to cast a Worksheetclass into a Worksheet interface.The error occurs when I try to set a cells value at the specified array point as a string value from the text file. I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Library.

```
public static _Worksheet SheetFromTxt(string fileName)
    {
        _Worksheet sheet = new Worksheet();
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            var rowCounter = 1;
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var columnCounter = 1;
                var values = line.Split(' ');
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    sheet.Cells[rowCounter, columnCounter] = value;
                    columnCounter++;
                }

                rowCounter++;
            }
        }
        return sheet;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting the exception here `_Worksheet sheet = new Worksheet();`? If yes, what is it exactly. Isn't `Worksheet` an interface? How do you imagine you can `new` it?

Comment: Instead of using Interop (which requires an Excel installation), use a library like EPPlus to create an `xlsx` file directly. Also, *separate* loading the original data from Excel generatino

Comment: You are, but the error message is not that intuitive.  The real problem is that you cannot create a Worksheet object like that.  You must use the factory method, Application.Worksheets.Add().  Lots of Google help when you simply query "c# excel create worksheet", always start there first.